# How do I set a property of an object from another file in cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I'm coding an iPhone app.

Instead of writing all the code here, this is basicly what I want to do:

testViewController.m:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad { label.text=@"text"; }
```

This works.
Now I want to change the label text from the testAppDelegate file.

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application { 
testViewController *tvc=[[testViewController alloc] init];
tvc.label.text=@"another text";
[tvc release];
 }
```

This isn't working!
How can I do this?

Thanks for all answers :)

Comment: It seemed you have two different instances of testViewController.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In applicationDidBecomeActive you are creating a new instance of the view controller (this is what alloc / init) setting the label text *in your new instance* and then releasing it.

You need to be referring to the actual instance of your view controller that is on the screen. This is probably already referred to somewhere in your application delegate - is it the root view controller, for example? When is it created in the first place?

You may need to set a property on your application delegate to hold a reference to this view controller. The code you have is fine except that you are talking to a new controller instead of the one that is presented on the screen - assuming of course that your label is a property on the view controller.

Answer (score 0):

In .h file: define property:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel *label;
```

In .m file: implement set/get methods for that propery (for example, automatically):

```
@synthesize label;
```

Comment: Read my question again! It's all about two different files.

Comment: Read the answer again!  It will let you do exactly what you asked.

Comment: Okei, I tried it. In the delegate .h file added the property and in the delegate .m I synthesized it. Then I just called it directly in the method as label.text=@"another text". Am I missing something? :)

Answer (score 0):

Declare testViewController as outlet in testAppDelegate.h, perform its binding in xib, probably MainMenu.xib, now try changing value of its label in -

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry! Should have specified more what I was doing. Now I've learned.
I had a tab-bar view controller template.

I solved this by adding in the delegate .h file:

```
@class testViewController
@property(nonatomic,retain) UIViewController *testViewcontroller;
```

and in the .m file:

```
@synthesize testViewController=_tvc;
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
 {
_tvc.label.text=@"another text";
}
```

And of course imported the testViewController.h and declearing the methods there too.

Thanks for all your responses :)